# IEnumerable Collection Binding to DetailsView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DetailsView control which gets data from a IEnumerable custom class.
But I can't get updated values from the control so I can process to update them manually in the database. How can I do that?

Regads,

Gustavo

Comment: what technologies are you using, is this winforms, wpf, silverlight, asp....?  it sounds like asp but im not sure.

Comment: @luke, ASP.NET I guess, since there's only one DetailsView class in the framework

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it can't work with an `IEnumerable`... The `DetailsView` probably needs to be able to access the data source by index (or at least a way to access a specific item of the data source), so I think the source has to implement `IList`. But I can't find anything about it in the documentation, so that's just a guess...

Comment: I figure it out, reading the index provided by the DataGridView control, and implementing a ICollection list, just not an IEnumerable one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some added clarification might be useful here, but some notes:

- the DetailsView can work with an IEnumerable source (assuming you're setting DataSource to the enumerable), but it'll bind to the first item fetched from the source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx#binding_to_data

- since it sounds like you're not binding to a data source, you'll need to hook up to an event (ItemUpdated in this case, I'd think) and then do the database update yourself

IMHO, if you can switch to binding against a 'real' data source life will be easier since you can let DetailsView do the heavy lifting for you, but if not, hopefully ItemUpdated will work for you :)